# How do I assign a value equivalent to a blob size to a string in Delphi?

Tags: xml, string, delphi, ms-word

How do I assign a value equivalent to a blob size to a string in Delphi? I am actively looking for any help.

My requirement is:

1. I have an automated word document object, in which we have certain document variables.
2. I replace those document variables with their appropriate values from an XML payload.
3. The current requirement is to replace one of the document variables with an already generated sub document itself, which I can decode or encode in readable as well as binary format.
4. While assigning that generated sub document to the main document (document variable), I face an error of `'String literal size too big'.`

Comment: [Operating parameter limitations and specifications in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/211489)

Comment: I concur with @fantaghirocco. I suggest you look at using a CustomXMLPart in the document, instead, to store this kind of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have helped if you had done what you're supposed to do here at SO and shown your code, especially for your item 4; readers can't see your screen and shouldn't have to guess exactly what it is that you're doing which provokes the error.  If you're still stuck after reading this answer, I suggest you edit your q to include your relevant code.

The following code seems to me to satisfy items 3 & 4 of your "requirements" as it shows one way to insert a structured document B into a document A which contains a field, without getting the error message you quoted.  Beware it's not very thoroughly tested, but it may at least get you going on the right lines.

```
procedure TForm1.CreateWordDoc;
var
  DocText : String;
  MSWord,
  Document,
  Document2,
  SourceRange,
  Table : OleVariant;
begin
  MSWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  MSWord.Visible := True;

 //  Create a document containing a field
  Document := MSWord.Documents.Add;
  DocText := 'Hello Word!';
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText(DocText);

  MSWord.Selection.Fields.Add(Range:= MSWord.Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty,
    PreserveFormatting:=False);
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText(Text:='afield');

  MSWord.Selection.MoveRight(Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2);

  // Create a second document containing some structured text
  Document2 := MSWord.Documents.Add;
  DocText := 'Second document';
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText(DocText);

  Table := MSWord.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(MSWord.Selection.Range, 2, 2);
  Table.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text := '1,1';
  Table.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text := '2,1';
  Table.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text := '1,2';
  Table.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text := '2,2';
  MSWord.Selection.EndKey( Unit:=wdStory);
  MSWord.Selection.TypeParagraph;

  Document2.Select;
  SourceRange := MSWord.Selection.Range;

  //  Now, copy document2 into the field in the first document
  //  For simplicity, this uses the index of the field to identify it
  Document.Fields.Item(1).Result := SourceRange;

end;
```

Finally, please note that in "Delphi-speak", the expression "blob" usually refers to a "binary large object" of the sort typically stored in a database field.  It doesn't seem that that is actually what you're asking about, though, and I'm not sure what the relevance of the title of your q is to the point of your question.

Comment: Did this answer your q or are you still stuck on something?

Comment: I am still having problems with my code. Some day this will work for me I hope it's today finally. 
Now everything is solved, but the formatting of the sub document which is being assigned to a placeholder is lost (like font, color, alignment etc). But it is not getting lost due to your code, i wrote something like this which is suspect because it is assigning it as a text:
`DocVariables.Values[PropName] := SourceRange.FormattedText.Text;`
Also, When i tried my luck to do `Document.Fields.Item(1).Result := SourceRange;` 
i am getting an error as "Requested object is not available"

Comment: Please please help @MartynA

Comment: I thought you had lost interest in this because you neither accepted my answer nor replied when I asked if you were still stuck.  Anyway, I cannot help you with your code because I cannot see it.  So, what you should do is to add the code you are trying to  use to your q and explain why it does not work as you wish.

Comment: Actually Martyn code is almost same what you have suggested in your answer. I am getting an error as **Error Code: -1, Error String: Requested object is not available** while assigning the document2 in the desired field of first document as written above `Document.Fields.Item(1).Result := SourceRange;`, so i thought to ask you for any clue.

Comment: Well, do you get the error when you use **exactly** my code?  If not, how **exactly** does your code differ?